# Show the content of Multiple select

Tags: ajax

i have this code but does not work i just want to put the content of the multiple combobox into textbox name valueholder and every value should be separated by comma. Thanks in advance, i dont know where to start im new in javascript thx

Example output in the textbox should be.

4800014145089,4800131590977

```
var ValuesArray = $('#countries').val(); 
    var holder = $('#valueholder').val(); 
    ValuesArray== valueholder;
    <input type="text" name="valueholder" id="valueholder">
          <select id="countries" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">

            <option value="4800014145089">4800014145089</option>
            <option value="4800131590977">4800131590977</option>

          </select>
          <br/>
```

Comment: you need whenever combobox change values to show in input `valueholder` right?

Comment: i need it when the page start to output the content of combobox

Comment: all the values? or selected ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with jquery:

```
$(function(){
    // get all the option tags
    var options = $('#countries option'); 

    // map the function for each option 
    var values  = $(options).map(function() { 
        return $(this).val(); 
    }).get();

    $('#valueholder').val(values.join(',')); 
});
```

See the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/qx5wkbd8/1/)